# Where are my cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://mydomain.com/myservice");
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
var cookies = resp.Cookies;
Console.WriteLine("Cookie count: {0}", cookies.Count);
```

Output is:

```
Cookie count: 0
```

I can see using Charles that the call to my web service is returning cookies.  Why don't they show up in my response's cookie collection?

Comment: Does `resp.Cookies.Count` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `CookieContainer` in your request object to accomodate the cookies:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://mydomain.com/myservice");
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
var cookies = resp.Cookies;
Console.WriteLine("Cookie count: {0}", cookies.Count);
```

From the Remarks section of the [documentation for the `CookieContainer` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx):

> `CookieContainer` is null by default.
>   You must assign a `CookieContainer`
>   object to the property to have cookies
>   returned in the `Cookies` property of
>   the `HttpWebResponse` returned by the
>   `GetResponse` method.